# How can I display my COUNT(*) query results in a <li> list including the number?

Tags: php, wordpress, mysqli

I have a database table of events. Each event has a place assigned to it. I want to display a numbered list of the 10 most used places. I would like to see it in the following format:

1. eventplace1 (place count)
2. eventplace2 (place count)

And so on.

Using PHP 7.2.12 and MySQL 5.6, and a beginner in php coding...

I figured out a code (the $query below) that gives the list I want in phpMyAdmin, but I want to use it in a widget on my WordPress homepage.

I know there is a SELECT TOP 10 which in theory should do what I am looking for, but it doesn't seem to work...

```
<?php
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
mysqli_select_db($connection, DB_NAME);

$query = "SELECT count(*), eventplace FROM tng_events GROUP BY eventplace HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 10";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
?>
```

When I do echo $result[0]; I just get the total count of all places.
When I do echo $result[1]; I get nothing, just an empty space.

When I use
SELECT count(*), eventplace FROM tng_events GROUP BY eventplace HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 10
in phpMyAdmin it gives a table with 10 places and their respective count number.

I want the output to be the same content as in phpMyAdmin, but in a slightly different form (see above). I suppose I need to create two variables ($), one containing the eventplace name, the other containing the count, but I'm not sure how to do that. Then the output would probably be something like:

echo < ol >< li >$eventplace ($placecount)< /li >< /ol >
(without the spaces)

Comment: You didn't show the line of code that creates the result set ($result).

Answer (score 0):

Using the foreach loop, you can iterate through the results and echo each element inside the loop as shown below.

```
$query = "SELECT count(*) as count , eventplace FROM tng_events GROUP BY eventplace HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 10";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

"<ol>";
foreach ($result as $row){
    echo "<li>" .$row['eventplace']. ' ('. $row['count']. ')'. "</li>";
}
"</ol>";
```